# Problem with uploading file Angular and Flask

Tags: angular, flask, file-upload

First of all excuse me if it's not well explained but I'll try my best.
I'm trying to upload files from my front(Angular) and I'm having troubles with it.
so far, this is my Service:

```
export class FileManagerService
{
    file: File = null;

    baseUrl: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
    public addFile(file: File) {
            const formParams = new FormData();
            formParams.append('file', file.data);
            return this._httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'upload', formParams);
    
        }

}
```

this is my component.ts :

```
onFilechange(event: any) {
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
    }


    upload() {
        if (this.file) {
            this._fileManagerService.addFile(this.file).subscribe((resp) => {
            alert('Uploaded');
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please select a file first');
        }
        }
```

and this my component.html

```
<div class="mt-4 sm:mt-0">
                <!-- Upload button -->
                <button (click)="this.upload()"
                (change)="this.onFilechange($event)"
                type="file" id="formFile"
                    mat-flat-button
                    [color]="'primary'">
                    <mat-icon [svgIcon]="'heroicons_outline:plus'"></mat-icon>
                    <span class="ml-2 mr-1">Upload file</span></button>
                    <input (change)="this.onFilechange($event)" class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
</div>
```

okay so when I try uploading a file I get in my console BAD REQUEST
[image]
and the file is undefined
[image]
any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have already grabbed `file` object and stored it inside `this.file`. Now while forming `FormData`, just pass the `file` object instead of `file.data`(which will be `undefined`)

```
formParams.append('file', file as any);
```

instead of

```
formParams.append('file', file.data);
```

Comment: I get this error //// (parameter) file: File
Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'File' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': arrayBuffer, slice, stream, textts(2345)

Comment: this is a ts problem
i get this error in my VSCode

Comment: @Alex on which line it throws an error? `formParams.append('file', file.data);` this one?

Comment: yes that line when i changed file.data to file I get that error

Comment: I was trying to reproduce the error, but can not re-produce. [Check this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBsFMBdQMwJZQFygGJMqAvKAdgK7jgDcAUGSKAMYD2eAzrHLQE4C2AIgIbTc75IAd3RsuvbgAoAlOSosOPPgDpuABzWQ8AE0kByRFD0AaeJlkU4BPNWgJ6oehijUAFtzwBzSJMgA3LWhUDwBPaVAAbzJQGJp6BlooZXBaT18AvGhlPlZvLMNIBgBtAAYAXQtYuMZmTAF-QOzuXJhlAuLy8irubW1nHwKLAF9La1t7PFAevsxJAtR+8KiYuhr4MSV+XDxhUUUJGS71-ZV1TR19ApMzKGGgA)

Comment: sir, i have a model i think the problem is from there 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/fr/play?#code/PTAEBsFMBdQMwJZQFygGJMqAvKAdgK7jgDcAUGSKAMYD2eAzrHLQE4C2AIgIbTc75IAd3RsuvbgAoAlOSosOPPgDpuABzWQ8AE0kByRFD0AaeJlkVIADzVtYCPNEis43algxRQAbzKh-oAjaAPyoTKwOAObkAWZQeNzskKGg4VExAdoSKQBCDtysAJ4AKoWaGf7QZclh0BF40X4BDAgAXpCo3HiF5GQAvmRwBHjU0Aj0oPSekNQAFl2RkJKQAG5a0J3d0j5N-nSMtFDK4LSRy2uOynysi9DKhpAMANoADAC6FrH7THFYuKvrK4FW73TDPd4VUDcbTaaaSB4WAaDYajcZ4KEwuEPVDTba+Pb0H4KcR8AR4YSiRQSGQZYlKbiqDRaXQGTAmX6IigUIA

Comment: i got the same error